# Delayed Recording Start in bigbluebutton

Tags: bigbluebutton

We use the recording and playback feature of bigbluebutton. Is there a way to kick off the recording feature of a already created meeting after the meeting is created? Basically we start the meeting 10 minutes prior to the actual start time to give the presenter time to upload presentation, check audio etc. We would like to start the actual recording only at the actual start time to prevent the 10 minute useless stuff during playback?

Is it possible through API or some console command? We have a way to do it either way..
Any help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could try enabling the autoRecord feature to start recording the session, whenever a meeting is created. You can check out the bigbluebutton property file located at- /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bigbluebutton/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties
Change the field autoStartRecording=true and restart bigbluebutton by sudo bbb-conf --restart
The recording button should now be automatically switched on, once you enter a meeting. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible after BigBlueButton 0.9.0 came. There is feature in meeting interface - start/stop recording button.

Please see more in official documentation: [Start/Stop Recording](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/overview/090overview.html#start/stop-recording)